# Windows 8 start screen will only find apps matching full words

Tags: windows-8

Since doing a fresh install of Windows 8 x64 RTM I'm having trouble starting apps from the start screen. In previous version I could just start typing the apps name and I would be presented with a list of matches that decreased in number as I continued typing.

In the RTM version I have to type complete words to find a match. i.e. if I want to run powershell I have to type in powershell before I get any hits. Like wise if I want to start Visual Studio I have to type visual before I get a match. If I continue and start typing Studio the match goes away and doesn't return until I finish typing studio.

This problem does not affect Setting or Files which show all possible matches.

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: There is nothing wrong.  I would assume this behavior is based on your current system's settings.

Comment: It seems pretty wrong to me, is this the normal experience in the RTM version? Is there anyway to change this 'system setting'?

Comment: You would change it the same way you would change any of the search options for Windows.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Check folder options Search Tab, be sure "find partial matches" is ticked.

Control Panel > Folder Options

[image]

Answer (score -1):

just get start8 :P save yourself all the trouble of learning annoying short-cuts lol.

start menu link: http://windowswise.com/windows-8-start-menu/

nothing like bringing the classic stuff back!